# (web dev beginner) How can I get URL of the web server that I wrote?

Tags: url, web, xampp

I am beginner in web development and I am now using XAMPP package to do my web programming.
I am just using localhost/files in web browser on my desktop to test it
But what if I want to access the web in any remote computer?
Also, did all web developers need to pay for the domain name/unique URL for the web they wrote?
Can I just use my desktop as the web server and once people access the web they just can do it by typing my host IP/sth like port number?

Hope you can understand my questions! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specifically set up your development machine to allow external IP's to access your computers network if you want to view a development site from a different machine. Quite cumbersome.

Either web developers or companies buy Domain Names, which uses DNS (Domain Name Service) to mask the IP address to the server with the address. You can buy Domain Names from many companies, on such as Namecheap.com

Hope that answers some of your questions.

Answer (score 2):

For computers connected on your local network, they can just use your internal IP instead of localhost to access your files. For example, if your IP is 192.168.1.100, other machines on the same network can access your web server via http://192.168.1.100/files.

It is technically possible to use your own computer as a web server. However, there are a few issues to tackle:

1. Unless your IP is static, binding a domain name to your IP will require an intermediate service like DynDNS.
2. Unless you're on a super fast Internet line, your computer's bandwidth will become a bottleneck when other users access your site.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to upload your files to a Webserver to access the files from a remote computer or use a service like dyndns.org to assign a dynamic domain to your computer (you need to forward port 80 through your router and firewall to your computer). But be aware your computer needs to stay online if you use the later.
People can also access by IP but that might change quite often.

According to the costs, yes almost all hosters will cost some money, but mostly it's a low cost for a small websit.

Answer (score 1):

I feel, you will have to take a hosting space by some Internet Hosting company. Other people cannot access your machine by Internet until it is exposed to Internet. Usually your machine is not directly on Internet, it is shadowed by Proxy of your internet provider. First you should talk to your Home Internet service provider for granting you a static IP... if that doesnt work then Go for Internet Hosting company like Godaddy or something.